# Laravel: Referencing a model dynamically

Tags: laravel

I have a few many to many relationship between one model (`Spendcode`) and a number of other ones (ie, `Order`, `OrderedItem`, `AnotherOrder`, `SomeOtherModel`).

Right now, I'm attaching and detaching these relationships using something like this:

```
public function attachSpendcodeToOrder($order, $spendcode){
  $order->spend_codes()->attach($spendcode->id);
}

public functio detachSpendCodeFromOrder($order, $spendcode){
  $order->spend_codes()->detach($spendcode->id);
}

public function attachSpendcodeToOrderedItem(){.... // you get the idea
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
public function toggleSpendcode($model, $spendcode){
  $targetModel = $model // whichever one I sent 
  $tagetModel->spend_codes->toggle($spendcode->id);
}
```

Is it possible to get the `$model` dynamically?

Thank you,

I could do this but looking for something cleaner

```
if ($type === 'Order') {
  // do this great thing
}

if ($type === 'OrderedItem'){
  // do this greater thing
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to do something like this:" what prevents you from doing that solution? That seems like it will work.

Comment: Thats my entire question :D, how do i get `$model` dynamically?

Comment: What is your input? what do you already have of values when you should be calling this method, i'm kinda confused. Getting a model dynamically is quite vague.